# Select from other table if value exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I created a fiddle for this, at this link:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e007

I could'nt find SQL compact / CE so it's in MySQL.

The tables looks like this

```
Records                      Clients
ID | NAME    | AGE           ID | NAME    
------------------           ----------------
1  | John    | 20            1  | John
2  | Steven  | 30            2  | Daniel
3  | Abraham | 30            3  |
4  | Donald  | 25            5  | Lisa 
6  |         | 35            6  | Michael
7  |         | 42            7  |
```

I would like to select from both tables, and if the id is in both tables and both have names I would like the the name from "Clients" as the default. If the name in Records is blank, use the client name (if any) and if the Clients.Name is blank; use the records.Name.

From tables above, i would like this:

```
ID | NAME    | AGE 
------------------
1  | John    | 20
2  | Daniel  | 30
3  | Abraham | 30
4  | Donald  | 25
5  | Lisa    |
6  | Michael | 35
7  |         | 42
```

How do i do this in SQL Compact?

EDIT:
Thanks to great answers below i've managed to come up with this query, which ALMOST works:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.age FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT r.id,
        CASE WHEN r.name = NULL THEN c.name ELSE r.name END  as name,
        r.age 
        FROM Records r 
        LEFT JOIN Clients c ON c.id = r.id
    )
    UNION 
    (
        SELECT c.id, c.name, null as age FROM Clients c where c.id NOT IN (select id from Records)
    )
) as t ORDER BY t.id
```

This gives me this output:

```
ID | NAME    | AGE 
------------------
1  | John    | 20
2  | Daniel  | 30
3  | Abraham | 30
4  | Donald  | 25
5  | Lisa    |
6  |         | 35
7  |         | 42
```

"Michael" (should be on #6) is missing in this case. Why?!

Comment: use this in the case part: `CASE WHEN c.name <> ''`

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ tried this as well, same result. "when c.name not is null use c.name else use r.name". "Michael" is missing, which is really confusing.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ sorry! you were completely right. <> NULL was wrong (even if the post actually is null), but when i changed to <> '' it worked. I'll give your answer the cred. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select r.id,
     IF(c.name != '',c.name,r.name) as name,
     r.age 
 FROM Records r 
 LEFT JOIN Clients c ON c.id = r.id 
 GROUP BY c.id
```

Use above query.

**EDITED:**

```
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.age FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT r.id,
        CASE WHEN c.name <> '' THEN c.name ELSE r.name END  as name,
        r.age 
        FROM Records r 
        LEFT JOIN Clients c ON c.id = r.id
    )
    UNION 
    (
        SELECT c.id, c.name, null as age FROM Clients c where c.id NOT IN (select id from Records)
    )
) as t ORDER BY t.id
```

Use this query.

Comment: Cool. But it skips "Lisa" since she's not in the Records table. Otherwise this is correct.

Comment: @gubbfett use the join only instead of the Left Join

Comment: if i use only join i only get 1,2,3,6,7. "Donald" and "Lisa" is missing.

Comment: @gubbfett use the Edited query this will work for you.

Comment: It feels like this is close, but i get errors.

Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'IF'.
Missing FROM clause.
The Derived Table SQL construct or statement is not supported.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.

Comment: i modified your answer with some other answers, and i almost got it right when i replaced the 'IF(....) as name' with this: 'CASE WHEN c.name = NULL OR c.name = '' THEN r.name ELSE c.name END as name'. In this case i get it almost correct, the only fail is that #4 name is NULL instead of "Donald". I tried the new edit but it still complains about the IF.

Comment: @gubbfett Instead of the `CASE WHEN c.name = NULL OR c.name = ''` use the `CASE WHEN c.name = '' ` only

Comment: @gubbfett I have edited the query of Edited part and test that it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use COALECSE to get the first not-null value:

```
select id, coalesce(clients.name, records.name) as correct_name, records.age
from records
join clients using (id);
```

EDIT: In case not existing names are stored as '' instead of NULL use:

```
select id, case when clients.name = '' then records.name else clients.name end as correct_name, records.age
from records
join clients using (id);
```

Of course you can also react on both '' and NULL by asking

```
when clients.name = '' or clients.name is null then
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e007/36.

Comment: Nice! But when i try this, i skips some values. In this case i just got the data for i 1,2,3,6,7

Comment: Ah, I see, instead of storing NULL what I expected, you store '' for missing names. I'm editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, in my test-setup i use null values. Null or '' does not really matter in this case, i can use them both. I've tried both of them with some tweaks, but i can't get them to work. As you can see in the fiddle, it leaves out some values from the Clients table, since the select is "FROM Clients" (?).

Comment: Sorry for that. You are right. I didn't see that there are ids missing in both tables. You need a FULL OUTER JOIN for this. As this is not available in your dbms you will have to replace this with a combination of left and right outer join. Look here how to do it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join

Answer (score 0):

```
    select case when a.id <> '' then a.id else b.id end as id ,
case when a.name <> '' then a.name else b.name end as name,a.age
 from records a 
full outer join clients b on a.Id = b.id
order by a.id
```

Comment: This is in SQL , will work fine for your senario as per the data in your sqlfiddle....

Comment: Oh sorry i have no idea about SqlCE my query works with SQL Server, check if any alternate for that

Answer (score 0):

please try,hope this will work..

```
select c.id,
IF(NAME='',(select name from Records where id = c.id),'')
If(NAME=NULL,(select name from Records where id = c.id),NULL)
Else c.NAME
from client c;
```

cheers!!!